# in javascript objects, do "static" functions and prototype functions share same namespace?

Tags: javascript, object, scope

regardless of the wisdom of such a naming scheme, is the following valid?

```
var F = function() {
  this.f1 = function() {}
}
F.f1 = function() {}

// "static" call
var v1 = F.f1();

// prototype call
var f = new F();
var v2 = f.f1();
```

it seems it should be ok since, for example, `var` and `this` variables within an object function do not share the same space.

Comment: There is actually nothing prototype related in this example.

Comment: @Felix Kling - then I am very confused.  I had thought that `f1()` in `var F = function(){ this.f1(){...} }` was identical to `F.prototype.f1 = function(){...}`

Comment: @August Lilleaas - valid in that their namespace does not overlap, qed, they are two distinct functions

Comment: @ccyoung: No it is not. `F.prototype` is *one* object from which all new objects will inherit. But with `this.f1 = ...` you are assigning the function to each new element (each element has its own function). It will *look* the same but the object structure is different. Have a look at the output (console) of this example: http://jsfiddle.net/fkling/5ewLe/

Comment: @Felix Kling - this makes sense - thanks for the clarity!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that is valid.

In your example, `F` is a function which you assign a property called `f1` which is a function itself. If you were to change the code to read `f = new F()`, then `f` is an object which inherits from `F`'s prototype, but they're still two distinct objects.

Comment: It does not have `F` at its prototype (at least I find the wording confusing). It inherits from `F`'s prototype...

Comment: Thanks Felix. I work with this stuff daily and I still find it confusing.

Answer (score 2):

It is valid.
Like the others have stated, there are no prototype related issues here.
You are attaching 2 propertyes to 2 different objects:

- the so called "static" function is attached to the function definition (F)
- the so called "public" function is attached to the object returned by the constructor (new F())

So, since `F !== new F()`, they are 2 different thing with different props.

If you want to make use of the prototypal inheritance, you can consider the following example:

```
 var F = function(){}
 // function visible to all of F's instances
 F.prototype.f1 = function(){console.log("I'm inherited!");}
 // a so called "static" function
 F.f1 = function(){console.log("I'm static!");}
 var instance1 = new F();
 var instance2 = new F();
 // function visible only to this instance of F
 instance1.f1 = function(){console.log("I'm visible only to this instance of F");}
```

Comment: what is the difference between the "private" f1 (as defined above) and the "prototype" f1 as you defined?  would there would be namespace conflicts.

Comment: it seems to me "private" is incorrect from the traditional object nomenclature.  anyone can access `this.f1 = `, whereas a truly "private" declaration would be `var f1 =`.

Comment: Define conflict:P. The "private" function overwrites the prototype one (only for that current instance). When you call `obj.method()`, if the method is not defined in the current object (such as our "private"), javascript looks up obj's prototypal chain and searches for that method.

Comment: sry, i ment to write public (i was thinking that it's private in the way that is different only for that instance). corrected the answer. sry 'bout that